# How do I delete the geth console history?

Tags: go-ethereum, security, console

how do I delete the geth console history ?

I'm concerned with this, especially in light of this recent Mist hack :

> On the console you can also unlock accounts (one at a time).
>
> `personal.unlockAccount(address, "password")`
>
> Note that we do NOT recommend using the password argument here, since
>   the console history is logged, so you may compromise your account. You
>   have been warned.

Comment: Note that the current version of `geth` does not record (properly formed) console commands that include a password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `history` file in Geth's `datadir` that you can delete.

The default `datadir` is:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
Linux: ~/.ethereum
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a history file in my datadir on my mac.....

Comment: i got it on my linux, try a real OS ;) joke aside I ran this regexp on my history and I never entered the pass so safe ;) `personal.unlockAccount\(.*(?<=,)(.*)(?=\))`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for windows but for linux / mac or anything bash this should work:

Your history is stored in `~/.bash_history`. So you can delete that file ( `rm ~/.bash_history` via CLI)

or edit that file to just remove the line where you typed the password

or run `history -c && history -w`

Then quit all instances of your terminal and reopen and press the up key to ensure everything is gone.

Also, don't run the non interactive versions of anything that require your password. I don't know why they include them. It's asking for trouble.

Comment: ATTENTION!!! This command is for the operative system history, to delete only the GETH console history see the [@eth answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3902/23349)